# how to make join or subquery perform on this table

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables

Table 1

```
Users:

id  | name      | function_id
-------------------------------
101 | Jaskaran  | 1,2,3
102 | Sandeep   | 2,4
103 | predeep   | 5,2
```

Table 2

```
function

id  | function
-----------------
1   | PHP
2   | Java
3   | C
4   | Ruby on Rails
5   | Python
```

How can we make join or sub query apply on these table and get user function with user records.

Comment: Normalise your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a poorly designed db schema. It is *always* a bad idea storing references to other tables as comma separated lists.

Having said that, you can use the following query to get the required result set:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.function_id,      
       GROUP_CONCAT(f.function) AS function_name
FROM Users AS u
LEFT JOIN Function AS f ON FIND_IN_SET(f.id, u.function_id) > 0
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

**Output:**

```
id  | name     | function_id | function_name
----+----------+-------------+---------
101 | Jaskaran | 1,2,3       | PHP,Java,C
102 | Sandeep  | 2,4         | Java,Ruby on Rails
103 | predeep  | 5,2         | Java,Python
```

Comment: whichone is fast normalization or this?

Comment: @Sandeep Normalization will give you better performance as well as simpler queries.

Answer (score 0):

Join syntax is. It will be helpful:

```
SELECT Users.ID,Users.name,
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN function
ON Users.function_id = Users.id ;
```